# Is there a way to accept the first letter of some input and check if it's within a certain list?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to take user input and check if its within a set of characters. if so then it should output some code

I've gotten past a few left or right handed error codes but now I cant seem to get it to recognize the set of initials.

```
    string gend = ""; //input
string Gend = gend.substr(0, 1); //accepts first character of input
string initial = 'm', 'M','f', 'F';

    cout << "Gender (M or F):" << endl;

cin >> gend;

while (Gend != initial){
    cout << "Wrong gender input. Please enter again. Gender (M or F):" << endl;
    cin >> gend;
    if (Gend == initial ) {
        (SOME CODE);
```

Using string has eliminated the error codes I was receiving. i.e. C2227 and C2228

Comment: `string Gend = gend.substr(0, 1);` needs to happen after you accept the input.

Comment: `string initial = 'm', 'M','f', 'F';` is not doing what you think it does

Comment: Please read about [mcve] and post some real code

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 just trying to learn here..

Comment: C2227 and C2228 are the errors you already fixed ? What are the errors now?

Comment: See `std::toupper`.  It will cut down the necessary size of your array.  See also `std::tolower`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than debug the given code, because there is a lot wrong with it, let's show you a couple easier ways to do this.

Maker a function that gets gender. This makes it really easy to stay in a loop until you have valid input. If you get something you can use, you return from the function. If not, you loop around and ask again.

For input of a single character, read in a `char`, not a `string`, unless you have a compelling reason to read the character in as a string.

Consider using  [`std::tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) or [`std::toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) to convert the `char` into a fixed case so that you don't have to test both cases. But for something really simple like this I would use a `switch` statement and test all 4.

Note that I'm always using the fully qualified name complete with identifier. This is because [`using namespace standard;` can cause some really interesting bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

```
char getGender(std::istream & in) // using a generic input stream so this function can be used 
                                  // with any input method
{
    while (true) // keep looping until the user gives valid input.
    {
        char gend; // only need one character, just read one character 
        if (in >> gend) // read the gender and test to be sure the stream isn't broken
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("The input stream is broken!");
            // throw an exception to force the program to deal with the broken stream or crash
        }
        switch(gend) 
        {
            case 'm':
            case 'M':
                // do stuff for male case
                return 'm';
            case 'f':
            case 'F':
                // do stuff for female case
                return 'f';
            default:
                cout << "Wrong gender input. Please enter again. Gender (M or F):" << endl;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

There is no way out of this function without an `'m'` or `'f'` other than the exception, and that needs special handling.

If all you want is an `'m'` or and `'f'` and you don't care which at this time, you can simplify things a bit with [the `std::strchr` function.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strchr)

```
char getGender(std::istream & in) // using a generic input stream so this function can be used 
                                  // with any input method
{
    while (true) // keep looping until the user gives valid input.
    {
        char gend; // only need one character, just read one character 
        if (in >> gend) // read the gender and test to be sure the stream isn't broken
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("The input stream is broken!");
            // throw an exception to force the program to deal with the broken stream or crash
        }

        if (std::strchr("mMfF", gend) != NULL)
        {
            return std::tolower(std::static_cast<unsigned char>(gend);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Wrong gender input. Please enter again. Gender (M or F):" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```